# <function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'char [256]' to 'std::wstring' and no instance for no instance of constructor matches the argument list

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Looks like I am getting the same 2 errors on one line of code. Can you help me? What am I doing wrong?

```
auto get_proc_base = [&](std::wstring moduleName) {
    MODULEENTRY32 entry = { };
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    std::uintptr_t result = 0;
    const auto snapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, r6_pid);
    while (Module32Next(snapShot, &entry)) {
        if (std::wstring(entry.szModule) == moduleName) {
            result = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(entry.modBaseAddr);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (snapShot)
        CloseHandle(snapShot);

    return result;
};
```

```
No instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=wchar_t, _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>, _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>]" matches the argument list
    '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'char [256]' to 'std::wstring'
```

Comment: Use `MODULEENTRY32W` and `Module32NextW` etc etc. Basically you need to be consistent. Either use narrow strings or wide strings throughout.

Comment: Cannot convert argument 2 from `MODULEENTRY32W` to `LPMODULEENTRY32 `getting this.

Comment: Looks like you missed part of John's comment: `Module32NextW` accepts and fills out a `MODULEENTRY32W`  and `MODULEENTRY32W` is what you need to get a `wchar` array to use with `wstring`. If you're counting on wide characters, you need the `...W` version of the win32 functions and data types. No point leaving this to chance with the `UNICODE`  build option, someone will <expletive deleted> that up sooner or later, so you might as well explicitly use the `...W` stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't construct a `std::wstring` from a `char[]` array, as you are trying to do.  `std::wstring` does not have a constructor for that purpose.  You would have to *convert* the `char` data to a `wchar_t[]` array using `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent, or to a `std::wstring` using `std::wstring_convert::from_bytes()`, or any other Unicode API/library conversion of your choosing (iconv, ICU, etc).

However, you don't actually need to do that in this case.  Since your lambda is taking a `std::wstring` as input, just use the Unicode-specific version of the Module32 API functions instead, ie using the `MODULEENTRY32W` struct with `Module32FirstW()`/`Module32NextW()`.

Also, you do need to call `Module32First/W()` before you can then call `Module32Next/W()`.

Try this instead:

```
auto get_proc_base = [&](const std::wstring &moduleName) {
    MODULEENTRY32W entry = { };
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(entry);

    std::uintptr_t result = 0;

    const auto snapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, r6_pid);
    if (snapShot)
        if (Module32FirstW(snapShot, &entry)) {
            do {
                if (moduleName == entry.szModule) { // alternatively: if (moduleName.compare(entry.szModule) == 0) {
                    result = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(entry.modBaseAddr);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (Module32NextW(snapShot, &entry));
        }
        CloseHandle(snapShot);
    }

    return result;
};
```